# Obj-C app doesn't load from start

Tags: ios, objective-c

I bult an iOS app and in  `-(void)viewDidLoad` I parse data from web, and display it on load. But often when I open my app it displays old data(app loads fast) and I need to kill it and open it again, after that it parses data and shows new. Why is that happening?

Comment: Do you test your app on the iOS Simulator or an actual device?

Comment: Actual device, in simulator it loads every time from start(that's good), it's like that device cache the app

Comment: `viewDidLoad` isn't called every time the view appears.

Comment: Have you checked (with an `NSLog`) whether the data is pulled from the server every time?

Comment: It works fine on simulator but doesn't on device

Comment: You should show some code.

Comment: it works on the simulator because you probably restart the app through Xcode each time.

Comment: I dont know how to post it better, I need to open and than close(kill) my app and then open it again to load new data, on first open it displays old data, and my parser is in  `-(void)viewDidLoad`

Comment: Please, read the official documentation before asking on SO

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't work that way because `viewDidLoad` is only called once, when the view is created.  After backgrounding and returning, your view still exists.

If you want to reload your data whenever the app returns from the background, you need to either override [`applicationDidBecomeActive:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationDidBecomeActive:) in your UIApplicationDelegate implementation, or you need to listen for the appropriate notification:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                             selector:@selector(applicationDidBecomeActive:) 
                                                 name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
                                               object:nil];
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    // reload your data here.
}
```

Don't forget to remove yourself as an observer when you no longer need the notification.

Comment: That is not what he was asking for.

Comment: If we take his question of "why doesn't this work" literally, yeah, I guess I forgot to say "It doesn't work because that's now how things work."  Instead I told him how to accomplish what he thinks should be happening.  Thank you for showing me the error of my ways.